# How to return values from array one by one on function call?

Tags: javascript

I want to return a value from an array in property "c" on every function call "loop". On the first call, I want to return only a first obj on second call second obj and on third call third obj from property c. ON forth function call accordingly first obj from property с. Please help  implement it

```js
const test = {
    a: {id: 1},
    b: {id: 2},
    c: [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {c: 3}]
}

function loop(elem) {
    if (test[elem] === elem) {
        test[elem].forEach(el => {
           return el
        })
    }
        return test[elem]
}
console.log(loop("c"))
```

Comment: That requires the function to keep state somewhere. You should look into *generators*, or into using a closure function whose usage would look like this: `const iter = loop(test.c); console.log(iter()); console.log(iter())`

Comment: Why? Perhaps there is a better solution to the real problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Also `test[elem].forEach(el => el)` does absolutely nothing

Comment: do you really want to 'return' here? it's more common to iterate and perform some kind of calculation.. In that case you could do what you're trying to do in a number of different ways. If you are trying to return then you will want to use a generator that will 'yield' a different value every time you call your generator function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a great use case for the [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).

Here's an example:

(Notice you need to add a `*` after `function` - this designates the function as a generator function.)

```js
const test = {
    a: {id: 1},
    b: {id: 2},
    c: [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {c: 3}]
}

function* loop(elem) {
    if (elem in test) {
        for (el of test[elem]) {
           yield el;
        }
    }
    
    yield test[elem];
}

// We need to store the output of the function so then we can reuse it.
const loopC = loop("c");

console.log(loopC.next().value);
console.log(loopC.next().value);
console.log(loopC.next().value);

// You can iterate over the entire array like so:
let result = loopC.next();

while (!result.done) {
    const value = result.value;
    result = loopC.next();
}
```

You need to store the output of loop("c") which will keep track of the array index and such. Then you can get the next value with `.next().value`. You can also see if you've finished the iteration by checking the `.done` property instead of `.value`.

Comment: Just a not on "*newly introduced generators*": generator functions were introduced in ES6 (aka. ES2015), so [using them is safe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*#Browser_compatibility) (as long as you don't have to support legacy browsers (e.g. IE)...)

Comment: @FZs I thought they were more recent, fixed my post, thank you.